# SQLite unable to open database file (code 14) on frequent "SELECT" query

Tags: android, sqlite, singleton, android-sqlite

I have following class "Singleton"  to handle SQLite connection and to make sure to have 1 instance of connection for whole process/app:

```
public class DBController {
  private static DBController instance = new DBController();
  private static DBHelper dbHelper;
  public static DBController getInstance()
  {
    return instance;
  }
  public SQLiteDatabase dbOpen(Context context)
  {
    if(dbHelper == null)
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    return dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }
}
```

And DBHelper class itself:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "database.db", null, 1);
  }
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    final String position = "CREATE TABLE test (" +
            "test TEXT NOT NULL);";
    db.execSQL(position);
  }
}
```

When I **frequently** try to "SELECT" some info from database I am receiving following error:

```
SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 31278 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:31278: (24) open(/data/user/0/uz.mycompany.myapp/databases/database.db-journal) - 
SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 31278 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:31278: (24) open(/data/user/0/uz.mycompany.myapp/databases/database.db-journal) - 
SQLiteLog: (14) statement aborts at 29: [SELECT * FROM test WHERE test='testdata1'] unable to open database file
SQLiteQuery: exception: unable to open database file (code 14); query: SELECT * FROM test WHERE test='testdata1'
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
```

I am running following code to execute query:

```
public String getData(Context context)
{
    SQLiteDatabase _db = dbOpen(context);
    Cursor c = _db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM test WHERE test='testdata1'", null);
    return getDataFromCursor(c).get(0); //gets data from cursor and returns first one
}
```

**How can I manage/improve my database connection to overcome/avoid this problem?**

Comment: Where do you pass the database **path**? You can see there's something wrong in this path: `open(/data/user/0/uz.mycompany.myapp/databases/database.db-journal)`. It should be something like `/data/data/uz.mycompany.myapp/databases/database.db`

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Thanks for reply, I think the problem is not related to database path... since My app is working and everything is fine until it comes to execution getData() frequently/often (on every 2 secs)...

Comment: `unable to open database file` tells you what?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi I think it can't open database file because it is already opened by another instance/thread? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If you didn't close it, of course. But I hope you close everything you open.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi The reason I have tried to implement singleton pattern is to keep database open while application is active

Comment: Which is **not** a good idea. `open, use, close`.

Comment: @Rotwang, `/data/user/0` is a symbolic link to `/data/data/`.

Comment: @HarryCho ... on **every** system?

Comment: @Rotwang, it was added on **Jelly Bean** so not **every** but **95%+** of android system currently according to Google's stats.

Comment: so, what if i need to do this in a loop? :
1. say there are 10 strings

2.And for each string, Open database, check a table for corresponding value. if value satisfies a statement,
3. query same database to get a value from another table.

Comment: @Dante it is always good practice to re-using same database for the batch queries

Comment: @JavaMachine yes. I’m using the same database. But different table. The thing is, I’m querying a set of values inside a loop. And for each returned value, I’m calling a method inside that loop itself to query another table of same database. So it’s loop(query->return values ->condition satisfied.=>2nd table query-> return values)->close database. Sorry. Its a long and complicated code. So unable to post it here, so just stating the process..

Comment: @Dante I got your point, in your code you want to open several cursors pointing to different tables. It is possible to do it. But keep in mind, opening cursors is costly, make sure you handle them properly (and of course reuse them where it is possible)

Comment: @JavaMachine  i am closing the 2nd cursor as soon as i processed those values and going to next value in the loop. But i am getting code 14 error at that particular cursor. 1st cursor is fine though.

Comment: @Dante maybe you are missing something? Opened read database for writing? another thread is trying to access database? More investigation is required :)

Comment: @JavaMachine IDK. I used get writable database and 1st cursor worked perfectly. I double checked. Real problem is the 2nd one, while the first cursor is still open. For now, i thought using 2 cursors at once will load the process & so i saved the 1st cursor results in arraylist and then used it for 2nd cursor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

before executing any query to this stuff (You should open your database). Close db after completion the task.

```
private DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);

try {
    _db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
} catch (SQLException s) {
    new Exception("Error with DB Open");
}
```

// Then write your query now.... and then close the db.

```
_db.close();
```

You can check out my [git link1](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/blob/master/StudentRegistration/src/gateways/DepartmentGateWay.java) [git link2](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/blob/master/StudentRegistration/src/gateways/DepartmentGateWay.java)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This might make my app a bit unpredictable, so my app requires to handle every request to database without skipping it...

Comment: Or I can force user to wait until database will be available to open (using your solution)... but will it be efficient in terms of user experience?

Answer (score 6):

As an addition, I believe that having too many cursors, and thus open's, can also result in the same "unable to open database file error".  (*in the following code, there's **507** rows in the **`shoplistcursor`**, so that was over **1500** cursors used/reused in total*)

I was getting the same message. As per :-

```
10-29 19:57:00.901 12845-12845/mjt.shopper E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30046 of [9491ba7d73]
10-29 19:57:00.901 12845-12845/mjt.shopper E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30046: (24) open(/data/data/mjt.shopper/databases/Shopper-journal) - 
10-29 19:57:00.901 12845-12845/mjt.shopper E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30046 of [9491ba7d73]
10-29 19:57:00.901 12845-12845/mjt.shopper E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30046: (24) open(/data/data/mjt.shopper/databases/Shopper-journal) - 
10-29 19:57:00.901 12845-12845/mjt.shopper E/SQLiteLog: (14) statement aborts at 24: [SELECT *  FROM productusage WHERE productailseref = 60 AND productproductref = 75 ;] unable to open database file
10-29 19:57:00.902 12845-12845/mjt.shopper E/SQLiteQuery: exception: unable to open database file (code 14); query: SELECT *  FROM productusage WHERE productailseref = 60 AND productproductref = 75 ;
10-29 19:57:00.902 12845-12845/mjt.shopper D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-29 19:57:00.903 12845-12845/mjt.shopper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

The code, that was in error, was :-

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor shoplistcursor = getAllRowsFromTable(SHOPLIST_TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor productcsr;
        Cursor aislecsr;
        Cursor prdusecsr;
        while(shoplistcursor.moveToNext()) {
            productcsr = getProductFromProductId(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_PRODUCTREF)));
            aislecsr = getAisleFromAisleId(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_AISLEREF)));
            prdusecsr = getProductUsage(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_AISLEREF)),
                    shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_PRODUCTREF)));
            if (productcsr.getCount() < 1 | aislecsr.getCount() < 1 | prdusecsr.getCount() < 1) {
                deleteShopListEntry(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_ID)));
            } 
            if(shoplistcursor.isLast()) {
                prdusecsr.close();
                aislecsr.close();
                productcsr.close();
            }
        }
        shoplistcursor.close();
        db.close();
}
```

The cure was to close the cursors on each iteration. As per :-

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor shoplistcursor = getAllRowsFromTable(SHOPLIST_TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor productcsr;
        Cursor aislecsr;
        Cursor prdusecsr;
        while(shoplistcursor.moveToNext()) {
            productcsr = getProductFromProductId(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_PRODUCTREF)));
            aislecsr = getAisleFromAisleId(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_AISLEREF)));
            prdusecsr = getProductUsage(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_AISLEREF)),
                    shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_PRODUCTREF)));
            if (productcsr.getCount() < 1 | aislecsr.getCount() < 1 | prdusecsr.getCount() < 1) {
                productcsr.close();
                aislecsr.close();
                prdusecsr.close();
                deleteShopListEntry(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_ID)));
            } else {
                productcsr.close();
                aislecsr.close();
                prdusecsr.close();
            }
        }
        shoplistcursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: I solved my problem with the help of @MikeT s answer I was also opening cursors within two loops hence cursors in the inner loop weren't closed, Hence I closed them in each iteration, Once their use is done :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code re-opens the database every time `dbOpen()` is called.

An SQLite database object is quite lightweight; it does not really make sense to keep closing and re-opening it.

You already have your singleton; just store a single `SQLiteDatabase` reference there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already tried to do that... I added `if(writableDB == null) writableDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); return writableDB;` in `dbOpen()` But it seems App is still trying to reopen opened database... I think I need to investigate on this...

Comment: You get a stack trace when the open fails. Either that one does not go through the singleton, or the singleton was deleted previously.

Answer (score 2):

I am using cursor for a big query where cursor hit the DB more than 1350 times by three seperate 'QUERY' within 800 milliseconds. So I got the error (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)). I solved it by closing the cursor before start a new query. That resolves my problem. Hope it will work the more big query than mine.

```
String data_query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id= " + c_id + " AND memberId = " + memberId;           
Cursor cu_cu = userHelper.getData(data_query);
float cu_cu_count = cu_cu.getCount();
System.out.println("ALL ANSWER COUNT : " + cu_cu_count);
cu_cu.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Application class

```
public static SQLiteDatabase database;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    SQLiteOpenHelper helper = Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    if (database == null) {
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    } else {
        if (!database.isOpen()) {
            database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    }
}
```

In your queries class

```
 public DataSources() {
    database = ApplicationController.database;
 }
```

That way you create a writeable db object once