# SQLite memory issue with singleton approach

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a SQLite database powering all the content in an Android app.

I have a DatabaseHelper class that extends SQLiteAssetHelper.

I have been having problems with too many instances of my database and then getting a SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException.

To counter this, I have changed my class to maintain a single instance of the DatabaseHelper object.

I have the following:

```
private static DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context, boolean singleRow, boolean showLoader){
    if(databaseHelper == null) {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context, singleRow, showLoader);
    }
    return databaseHelper;
}

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, boolean singleRow, boolean showLoader){
    super(context, (new File(DatabaseManager.getDatabasePath(context))).getName(), (new File(DatabaseManager.getDatabasePath(context))).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath(), null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    this.context = context;
    this.singleRow = singleRow;
    this.showLoader = showLoader;

}
```

I then call the getInstance static method as follows:

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext(), false, false);
```

After a certain amount of database activity, the app is still crashing on memory grounds.

I then get this error:

```
Error Code : 2062 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EMFILE)

Caused By : Application has opened two many files. Maximum of available file descriptors in one process is 1024 in default.

(unable to open database file (code 2062))
```

Having taken the singleton approach, I'm a bit lost for why this is still causing this memory leak.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps check to see if you have Cursors that are not being closed. I do recall having a similar issue but I don't recall it indicating the 1024 as being too many. I'll try to locate the post I made in regard to this.

Comment: [SQLite unable to open database file (code 14) on frequent “SELECT” query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008632/sqlite-unable-to-open-database-file-code-14-on-frequent-select-query/40317770#40317770) is the post. The message(s) are different, but I think it's clear that a Cursor results in a file being opened.

Comment: I have taken a look into this cursor issue and I found that I had quite a few open cursors. Haven't closed them all, it seems to have resolved the issue. I haven't carried out extensive testing though, so I'm not 100% sure. It's certainly got me past the blocking point where I was before. Could I ask you to put an informative answer in based on the cursors so that it can be left for others to see? It's the correct answer for me with this particular error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting a message indicating too many files open, a cause may well be that there are too many Cursor that are still open.

However, the message returned may not always be the same and is probably specific to the task/call being called.

In this case the message was `(unable to open database file (code 2062))`, yet in another case (from a SELECT the message was `unable to open database file (code 14)`). [SQLite unable to open database file (code 14) on frequent “SELECT” query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008632/sqlite-unable-to-open-database-file-code-14-on-frequent-select-query/40317770#40317770).

The above link also points to a post I made what quite clearly shows that creating a Cursor results in a file (or files) being opened.

The example was looping through about 500 rows and for each row it was creating/recreating 3 cursors for each row (so potentially 1500+ cursors even though only using 4 cursor objects).

Initially it was only closing the 3 cursors at the end (last row of the parent of all) resulting in the `unable to open database File (code 14)`. Closing the 3 cursors for each iteration resolved the issue.

The code that failed was :-

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor shoplistcursor = getAllRowsFromTable(SHOPLIST_TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor productcsr;
        Cursor aislecsr;
        Cursor prdusecsr;
        while(shoplistcursor.moveToNext()) {
            productcsr = getProductFromProductId(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_PRODUCTREF)));
            aislecsr = getAisleFromAisleId(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_AISLEREF)));
            prdusecsr = getProductUsage(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_AISLEREF)),
                    shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_PRODUCTREF)));
            if (productcsr.getCount() < 1 | aislecsr.getCount() < 1 | prdusecsr.getCount() < 1) {
                deleteShopListEntry(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_ID)));
            } 
            if(shoplistcursor.isLast()) {
                prdusecsr.close();
                aislecsr.close();
                productcsr.close();
            }
        }
        shoplistcursor.close();
        db.close();
}
```

Whilst the fixed code was :-

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor shoplistcursor = getAllRowsFromTable(SHOPLIST_TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor productcsr;
        Cursor aislecsr;
        Cursor prdusecsr;
        while(shoplistcursor.moveToNext()) {
            productcsr = getProductFromProductId(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_PRODUCTREF)));
            aislecsr = getAisleFromAisleId(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_AISLEREF)));
            prdusecsr = getProductUsage(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_AISLEREF)),
                    shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_PRODUCTREF)));
            if (productcsr.getCount() < 1 | aislecsr.getCount() < 1 | prdusecsr.getCount() < 1) {
                productcsr.close();
                aislecsr.close();
                prdusecsr.close();
                deleteShopListEntry(shoplistcursor.getLong(shoplistcursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPLIST_COLUMN_ID)));
            } else {
                productcsr.close();
                aislecsr.close();
                prdusecsr.close();
            }
        }
        shoplistcursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

I tend to now follow the following rule/practice :-

- If just getting the result e.g. getting the number of rows, close the Cursor in the method.
- If using the Cursor for a display e.g. a ListView, then close the cursor in the activity's `onDestroy` method.
- If using the Cursor for what I'll call more complex processing e.g. deleting rows with underlying references then close the cursors as soon as they are done with, within the processing loop(s).

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know why and really got curious about "Application has opened two many files" error and would like to know what causes it.

However, i use singleton with database without any issues over a year. I used this snippet to get database with singleton in 14 apps and never had any problems.

```
public class DatabaseManager {

    private AtomicInteger mOpenCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    private static DatabaseManager instance;
    private static SQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private DatabaseManager() {

    }

    public static synchronized DatabaseManager getDatabaseManager(SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseManager();
            mDatabaseHelper = helper;
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static synchronized DatabaseManager getDatabaseManager(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseManager();
            mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Get a writable database
     */
    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        if (mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
            // Opening new database
            mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            // System.out.println("DataBaseManager: Database Opened");
        } else {
            // System.out.println("DataBaseManager: Database Already Open");
        }
        return mDatabase;
    }

    public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
        if (mOpenCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            // Closing database
            mDatabase.close();
            // System.out.println("DataBaseManager: Database Closed");
        } else {
            // System.out.println("DataBaseManager: Database is NOT Closed");
        }
    }
}
```

onCreate() i get instance with  `mDatabaseManager = DatabaseManager.getDatabaseManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());`, onStart() i open database with `mDatabaseManager.openDatabase();`, and onStop() close it with `mDatabaseManager.closeDatabase();`

Comment: Little bit different from what I've got, have you got any code of how you use it?

Comment: @sark9012  I added methods for using it too.

Answer (score 1):

I do the singleton approach as well. There are two ways to access your Data obviously.

You can use a Cursor to populate a list of objects and then close your cursor and then close your DB.

Unless you are returning the cursor for dynamic paging of content because of larger list.

Whether or not to close your connection is contingent upon frequency of usage and your app's specific needs.

However, if you are accessing from new context and sharing the previously created SQLHelper class you could be creating memory leak issues as the constructor requires the context.

It sounds to me like you have too many files open on that single connection though. Have you considered closing your db connection after each interaction. Example:

```
public static ArrayList<OrderModel> getOrders(Context context){
    ArrayList<OrderModel> orderList = new ArrayList<OrderModel>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try{
        db = A35DBHelper.openDatabase(context);
        String columns[] = {
                "*"
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(OrdersTable.TABLE_NAME, columns, OrdersTable.COLUMN_PRIMARY_ID, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
                OrderModel order = new OrderModel();
                order.setLocalDatabaseId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrdersTable.COLUMN_PRIMARY_ID)));
                order.setID(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrdersTable.COLUMN_REPAIR_ORDER_NUMBER)));
                order.setOrderNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrdersTable.COLUMN_ORDER_NUMBER)));
                order.setCreatedAtDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrdersTable.COLUMN_CREATED_AT_DATE)));
                order.setImageCount(MediaDataContext.getAllMediaForOrderId(context, order.getID()).size());
                order.setDefaultThumbnailUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrdersTable.COLUMN_DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL_URL)));
                orderList.add(order);

            }

            cursor.close();

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        A35Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get orders: " + ex.getMessage());

    }

    A35DBHelper.closeDatabase(db);
    return orderList;

}
```

Then my singleton class has the open and close where if the context has changed I new up a new instance of the helper before opening.

Then I use the CloseUtil for try/catch closing each time.
This can still be the same if you are returning the Cursor Object instead of an ArrayList as you are possibly getting dynamic data that handles paging or is to big to fill a list.

But sounds like to me your connection is getting over worked so you may need to revisit your model.