# Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException unable to open database file (code 14)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-download-manager

From Crashlytics I am getting exception, I am using download manager to download files:

Here is code:

```
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(videoURL));


        File folder = new File(dir + "" + File.separator + (isAudio ? AUDIO : IMAGES));
        if (folder == null) {
            return;
        }
   try {
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                                | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                        .setTitle("Test")
                        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN)
                        .setDescription(id)
                        .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, isAudio ? AUDIO : IMAGES, fileName);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

                enqueue = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Here is the stacktrace from the logcat:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)


Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file (code 14)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1279)
       at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:1021)
       at PACKAG_NAME.FrontEngine.enqueueDownload(FrontEngine.java:1041)
       at PACKAG_NAME.ChatActivity.downloadMessageFile(ChatActivity.java:575)
       at PACKAG_NAME.BaseActivity.downloadFilesFromConversationItem(BaseActivity.java:1117)
       at PACKAG_NAME.BaseActivity$6.doInBackground(BaseActivity.java:751)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I could not find the reason, It is working fine on more than 40 device, only one crash reported, I have also deny the application permission from but working fine. 
Can anyone have any idea about it. Should I use put enqueue method in the try catch?

Comment: the error you are getting is it above android 5.0 device?

Comment: Yes buddy, I have all the devices running 7 OS. Only one crash has been reported in couple of months

Comment: You may wish to have a look at [SQLite unable to open database file (code 14) on frequent “SELECT” query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008632/sqlite-unable-to-open-database-file-code-14-on-frequent-select-query). In short there can be a number of reasons for this.

Comment: @MikeT I am not directly using sqlite, It is from Download Manager.

Comment: @RameshKumar did you find any solution for this? I'm also getting this from Download Manager