Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed? Android Room ORM
I am using a Room database. I start the database in onCreate and close it in onDestroy. However, when I enter the activity for the second time, I encounter the following error.
As can be seen in the log, after starting Room, I check with the log and I get a false response saying "isOpen", and there is also a callback in the database. Here, when it is open, it says open. I don't understand whether it is related to a delay or whether the isOpen() method is running. but after all this it gives me the error in the title
 DATABASECHECK isOpen: false // my log
 Invalidation tracker is initialized twice :/.
 DATABASECHECK Database open // my log
 (1) no such table: room_table_modification_log in "SELECT * FROM room_table_modification_log WHERE invalidated = 1;"
 Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM room_table_modification_log WHERE invalidated = 1;
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1463)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:901)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:62)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:2063)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:2038)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.kt:156)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.kt:484)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query$default(RoomDatabase.kt:478)
    at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$refreshRunnable$1.checkUpdatedTable(InvalidationTracker.kt:408)
    at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$refreshRunnable$1.run(InvalidationTracker.kt:373)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

Database Class
@Database(entities = {UserFood.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class UserFoodDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public static volatile UserFoodDatabase userFoodDatabase;

    public abstract UserFoodDao daoAccess();

    public static UserFoodDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (userFoodDatabase == null) {
            synchronized (UserFoodDatabase.class) {
                if (userFoodDatabase == null) {
                    userFoodDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    UserFoodDatabase.class, USER_FOODS_DB_NAME)
                            .addCallback(roomCallback)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return userFoodDatabase;
    }

    public static Callback roomCallback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            Log.e("DATABASECHECK", "Database created");
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA encoding = 'UTF-8';");
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            Log.e("DATABASECHECK ", "Database open");
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA encoding = 'UTF-8';");
        }
    };
}

FoodListActivity
public class FoodListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    UserFoodDatabase userFoodDatabase;
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list);

        userFoodDatabase = UserFoodDatabase.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        Log.e("DATABASECHECK", "isOpen: " + userFoodDatabase.isOpen());
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                userFoodDao = userFoodDatabase.daoAccess();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadData();
                    }
                });
            } finally {
                executor.shutdown();
            }
        });
  }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("TAG_LIFE", "onDestroy");
        userFoodDatabase.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}

I could not find an answer to this type of error in Room database solutions.

Don't close the database, there is no need.

@MikeT Hello, I read a lot of your posts on StackOverflow and got informed. I wanted to thank you for seeing you. I have more than one database in my application and I am getting the CursorWindowAllocationException error, I do not know what is causing this. So I came to the conclusion that I should close every activity when it destroys.. android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.

Rather than close the database, close the Cursors when finished with them (perhaps in onDestroy). However the most common issue is trying retrieve data where a row exceeds the size of the CursrorWindow, very often with images.

How to turn off cursor for room rom? Also why don't you suggest shutting down the database?

Closing the database and then opening it again is resources intensive, plus as you found it can result in issues as the underlying open helper may consider it still open (I think). Closing a Cursor should effectively turn that specific Cursor (in short the Cursor is a temp dataset/file, there is a limit to how many files can be open (about 1000 iirc)) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008632/sqlite-unable-to-open-database-file-code-14-on-frequent-select-query/40317770#40317770

I cannot relate the example here via its own android room database ORM. I know that opening and closing a database is very costly, but I encounter errors such as cursorwindowallocationexception cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. Additionally, there are approximately 25 databases in the application. That's why I want to close it in unnecessary places. Is this wrong? For example, isn't it correct to close SavedDatabase when exiting SavedActivity? @MikeT

a) Are you sure that the allocation failed message is actually resulting in an exception? Sometimes the message will appear in the log, but the offending row has then been omitted from the Cursor. b) Why 25 databases? Are you perhaps under the impression (based upon the 1 table for the UserFoodDatabase) that every table needs a single database (this is not the case). A database can have many tables. The entities parameter of the @Database annotation can specify many tables (@Entity annotated classes). Typically a single database would be used for an application.

a) Yes, especially on my Android 8.1 device, sometimes this cursorwindowallocationexception cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. I am encountering the error. But unfortunately I can't find a solution because I don't know which database it is in.
b) Yes, there are too many database tables and I will think about revising them again and reducing the number. I made a very unnecessary expense.

a) then you are probably storing too much data per row and at some stage a single row exceeds about 2Mb so it cannot be retrieved directly. Storing media rather than a link to the media file is very frequently a cause. b) too many tables is not an issue, too many databases (each consuming memory very much the same irrespective of the number of tables) could be an issue. So look towards reducing the number of databases (at a guess combining tables into probably a single database).

because I don't know which database it is in.  Amend  your callback's to include the database's path in the logged message. e.g. from Log.e("DATABASECHECK", "Database created"); to Log.e("DATABASECHECK", "Database " + db.getPath() + " created");

Hello, I tried many things to encounter the error I encountered before, but now I cannot get the "cursorwindowallocationexception cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed" error that I mentioned. Can you please give me a bad example? For example, what does this mean? "a) then you are probably storing too much data per row and at some stage a single row exceeds about 2Mb so it cannot be retrieved directly." @MikeT
